# Maximum number of login session on the linux machine

Tags: linux, session, networking

I have tried setting a restriction in `/etc/security/limits.conf` as below

- hard maxsyslogins 2
  root hard maxlogins    2

It is not working. Can anyone help with this?

Debian 4.9.144-3 (2019-02-02) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 2):

As per the man pages for limits.conf:

```
       maxlogins
           maximum number of logins for this user (this limit does not apply to user
           with uid=0)

       maxsyslogins
           maximum number of all logins on system; user is not allowed to log-in if
           total number of all users' logins is greater than specified number (this
           limit does not apply to user with uid=0)
```

Since the root user has a uid of 0, maxlogins and maxsyslogins for root will therefore not apply